# java Synchronized method does not work as expected,

Tags: java, synchronization

I have an synchronized method whose class object is being shared by two threads, but when I run this code , synchronization doesn't seem to work, am I missing a point here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class Main {

static class Bar {
    private int count = 0;
    public synchronized void increment(int value) {
        count += value;
    }
}

static class CustomThread extends Thread {
    Bar b;
    int threadNumber;

    Thread1(Bar b, int threadNumber){
        this.b = b;
        this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i <=25; i++) {
            b.increment(1);
            System.out.println("THREAD " +  threadNumber + " " + b.count);
        }
    }
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    CustomThread t1 =new CustomThread(bar, 1);
    CustomThread t2 =new CustomThread(bar, 2);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

I was expecting an output something like the following (`THREAD 1 (1 to 25`) then `THREAD 2 (1 to 25)`) but did not get it.

Output is:

```
THREAD 2 2
THREAD 1 1
THREAD 2 3
THREAD 1 4
THREAD 2 5
THREAD 1 6
THREAD 2 7
THREAD 2 9
THREAD 1 8
THREAD 1 11
THREAD 2 10
THREAD 2 13
THREAD 1 12
THREAD 1 15
THREAD 2 14
THREAD 2 17
THREAD 1 16
THREAD 1 19
THREAD 2 18
THREAD 2 21
THREAD 1 20
...
```

Comment: Can you add the actual output to the question please?

Comment: *then THREAD 2* - why would you expect this?

Comment: 1.) The given code does not compile. The constructer should be named CustomThread and the final closing brace is missing

Comment: 2.) the increment method should return the new value of count. You should never access the field count directly. It should be private and all access must be synchronized. (Also if you add a getter method, this should be synchronized too)

Comment: Threads can be executed in any order.  synchronization only allows one thread to execute that method at any point which thread comes first to that method that's the job of the OS.  If you want Thread 1 then Thread 2 every time then your gonna have to look into more [complex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) mechanisms

Comment: 3.) General hint: for this same purpose of thread-safe increment, there are perfect solutions available in the JDK. Rather use an AtomicInteger (java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger).

Comment: 4.) Thread execution order is unpredictable. 'Sync it' already said all I wanted to say too.

Comment: @ HooNose true.  Just giving him ideas on where to go from here

Answer (score 0):

If you want THREAD 1 first then THREAD 2, then do

```
t1.start();
t1.join();
t2.start();
```

But why would you want this when using Threads?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of `synchronized` both threads run at the same time.

`increment` on shared `Bar` is synchronized, so the incrementing is atomic:
1, 2, 3, 4, ... and not like the unsynchronized 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, ... .

The printlns happen outside the synchronized parts and may come out of order.
But especially `b.count` might be stale, not updated in the other thread due to a missing `volatile`.

To have a more sure, clear view of all do:

```
public synchronized int increment(int value) {
    count += value;
    return count;
}

        int c = b.increment(1);
        System.out.println("THREAD " +  threadNumber + " " + c);
```

Be aware that `System.out.println` is a single very slow resource, and made it possible that they executed alternately.